# spring boot/thymeleaf foreach, error on handling controller

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

i have object which has List and all this list has another List inside. problem is, i couldn't find the way nested looping with th:object attribute and i found solution from internet. currently i am having error when i am handling on controller but on thymeleaf UI there are no any errors.

successfully write to database that nested Object

error:

> 2023-11-23 13:39:55.795 ERROR 56621 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'clients[0].children[0]' of bean class [com.JJEP.JJEP.application.ApplicationRequestDTO]: Illegal attempt to get property 'children' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'clients[0].children' of bean class [com.JJEP.JJEP.application.ApplicationRequestDTO]: Could not instantiate property type [com.JJEP.JJEP.application.client.child.ChildRequestDTO] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.JJEP.JJEP.application.client.child.ChildRequestDTO.()] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.JJEP.JJEP.application.client.child.ChildRequestDTO.()

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="h-full" lang="en" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{_layout.html}" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<div layout:fragment="content">

  <div th:if="${param.error}" class="bg-red-100 border-l-4 border-red-500 text-red-700 p-4 rounded-xl m-4" role="alert">
    <p class="font-bold">Application error</p>
    <p th:text="${error} ?: 'Something went wrong. Please try again later'"></p>
  </div>
<!--  th:if="${#strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'true')}"-->
  <form  method="post" th:action="@{/application-handler}" th:object="${formApplication}">
    <div th:each="client: *{clients}">
      <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row p-4 justify-start">
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 mb-8">
          <h1 class="font-semibold">
            Client
          </h1>
          <p class="text-gray-500">
            Assets
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 flex-1 lg:mr-32">
          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="familyName" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Family name</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].familyName}" type="text" name="familyName" id="familyName" autocomplete="name" class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full" min="0" max="3.4028235E38"
              >
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Forename</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input
                      th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].forename}"
                      type="text"
                      name="forename"
                      id="forename"
                      autocomplete="name"
                      class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                      min="0"
                      max="3.4028235E38"
              >
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Marital Status</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].maritalStatus}" type="text" name="maritalStatus" id="maritalStatus" autocomplete="name" class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full" min="0" max="3.4028235E38"
              >
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Date Of Birth</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input
                      th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].dateOfBirth}"
                      type="date"
                      name="dateOfBirth"
                      id="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="name" class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                      min="0"
                      max="3.4028235E38"
              >
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">UK Domicile for IHT?</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input
                      th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].isUkIht}"
                      type="number"
                      name="isUkIht"
                      id="isUkIht"
                      autocomplete="name"
                      class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                      min="0"
                      max="3.4028235E38"
              >
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Was the deceased's spouse's NRB used?</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input
                      th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].isSpouseNrb}"
                      type="number"
                      name="isSpouseNrb"
                      id="isSpouseNrb"
                      autocomplete="name"
                      class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                      min="0"
                      max="3.4028235E38"
              >
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="md:m-0">
            <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">LPA in place?</label>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <input
                      th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].isLpa}"
                      type="number"
                      name="isLpa"
                      id="isLpa"
                      autocomplete="name"
                      class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                      min="0"
                      max="3.4028235E38"
              >
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
               class="md:m-0 col-span-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center space-x-4">
<!--      GAVNO CODE бля я не ебу как по другому     -->
            <a th:if="${clientStat.index == 1 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'true')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=true, client1children=${client1children}, client2children=${client2children + 1})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Add child</a>
            <a th:if="${clientStat.index == 0 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'true')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=true, client1children=${client1children + 1}, client2children=${client2children})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Add child</a>
            <a th:if="${clientStat.index == 0 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'false')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=false, client1children=${client1children + 1}, client2children=${client2children})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Add child</a>
            <a th:if="!${param.doubledClients}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=false, client1children=${client1children + 1}, client2children=${client2children})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Add child</a>
            <a th:if="!${param.doubledClients}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=true, client1children=${client1children}, client2children=${client2children})}"
               class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Add one more client</a>
            <a th:if="${#strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'false')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=true, client1children=${client1children}, client2children=${client2children})}"
               class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Add one more client</a>
            <a th:if="${clientStat.index == 1 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'true')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=false, client1children=${client1children}, client2children=${client2children - client2children})}"
               class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Remove client</a>
          </div>

          <!-- submit or save -->
          <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full flex flex-row justify-end border-t pt-4 space-x-4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div th:each="child : *{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].children}" class="flex flex-col md:flex-row p-4 justify-start">
          <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 mb-8">
            <h1 class="font-semibold">
              Child
            </h1>
            <p class="text-gray-500">

            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 flex-1 lg:mr-32">

            <div class="md:m-0">
              <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Name</label>
              <div class="mt-2">
                <input
                        th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].children[__${childStat.index}__].name}"
                        type="text"
                        name="childName"
                        id="childName"
                        autocomplete="name"
                        class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                        min="0"
                        max="3.4028235E38"
                >
                <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="md:m-0">
              <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Date of birth</label>
              <div class="mt-2">
                <input
                        th:field="*{clients[__${clientStat.index}__].children[__${childStat.index}__].dateOfBirth}"
                        type="date"
                        name="childDateOfBirth"
                        id="childDateOfBirth"
                        autocomplete="name"
                        class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                        min="0"
                        max="3.4028235E38"
                >
                <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center space-x-4">
              <a th:if="${clientStat.index == 0 and client1children >= 1 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'true')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=true, client1children=${client1children - 1}, client2children=${client2children})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Remove child</a>
              <a th:if="${client1children >= 1 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'false')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=false, client1children=${client1children - 1}, client2children=${client2children})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Remove child</a>
              <a th:if="${clientStat.index == 1 and client2children >= 1 and #strings.equals(param.doubledClients, 'true')}" th:href="@{/application(doubledClients=true, client1children=${client1children}, client2children=${client2children - 1})}" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-xl text-link hover:bg-link-back_hover">Remove child</a>
            </div>


          <!-- submit or save -->
          <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full flex flex-row justify-end border-t pt-4 space-x-4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>

      <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 mb-8">
        <h1 class="font-semibold">
          Joint
        </h1>
        <p class="text-gray-500">
          Assets
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 flex-1 lg:mr-32">

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Primary Property</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                    th:field="*{primaryProperty}"
                    type="number"
                    name="property"
                    id="property"
                    autocomplete="name"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                    min="0"
                    max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('primaryProperty')}" th:errors="*{primaryProperty}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="uk-property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">UK Holiday Home</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                    th:field="*{ukHolidayHome}"
                    type="number"
                    name="uk-property"
                    id="uk-property"
                    autocomplete="name"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                    min="0"
                    max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ukHolidayHome')}" th:errors="*{ukHolidayHome}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="btl-property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">BTL Property</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                    th:field="*{btlProperty}"
                    type="number"
                    name="btl-property"
                    id="btl-property"
                    autocomplete="name"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                    min="0"
                    max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('btlProperty')}" th:errors="*{btlProperty}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="foreign-property" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Foreign Property</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                    th:field="*{foreignProperty}"
                    type="number"
                    name="foreign-property"
                    id="foreign-property"
                    autocomplete="name"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                    min="0"
                    max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('foreignProperty')}" th:errors="*{foreignProperty}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full">
          <label for="foreign-will" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Foreign Will</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <select
                    th:field="*{foreignWill}"
                    style="-webkit-appearance: none;"
                    id="foreign-will" name="select"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
            >
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('foreignWill')}" th:errors="*{foreignWill}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="investment" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Investment</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                    th:field="*{investment}"
                    type="number"
                    name="investment"
                    id="investment"
                    autocomplete="name"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                    min="0"
                    max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('investment')}" th:errors="*{investment}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="savings-cash" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Savings & Cash</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                    th:field="*{savingsCash}"
                    type="number"
                    name="savings-cash"
                    id="savings-cash"
                    autocomplete="name"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                    min="0"
                    max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('savingsCash')}" th:errors="*{savingsCash}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
        <label for="personal-live-cover" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Personal Life Cover</label>
        <div class="mt-2">
            <input
                th:field="*{personalLifeCover}"
                type="number"
                name="personal-live-cover"
                id="personal-live-cover"
                autocomplete="name"
                class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
                min="0"
                max="3.4028235E38"
            >
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('personalLifeCover')}" th:errors="*{personalLifeCover}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0">
          <label for="trust" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Already in trust?</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <div class="mt-2">
              <select
                      th:field="*{trust}"
                      style="-webkit-appearance: none;"
                      id="trust"
                      name="select"
                      class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
              >
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
              </select>
              <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('trust')}" th:errors="*{trust}"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full">
          <label for="blood-protection" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Blood Protection</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <select
                    th:field="*{isBloodProtection}"
                    style="-webkit-appearance: none;"
                    id="blood-protection" name="select"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
            >
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('isBloodProtection')}" th:errors="*{isBloodProtection}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full">
          <label for="generation-iht" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Generation IHT</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
            <select
                    th:field="*{isGenerationIht}"
                    style="-webkit-appearance: none;"
                    id="generation-iht" name="select"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full"
            >
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-xs text-red-500" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('isGenerationIht')}" th:errors="*{isGenerationIht}"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full">
          <label for="notes" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">Notes (Optional)</label>
          <div class="mt-2">
              <textarea
                    th:field="*{notes}"
                    id="notes"
                    name="about"
                    rows="3"
                    class="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-xl focus:outline-primary block w-full">
            </textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <!-- submit or save -->
        <div class="md:m-0 col-span-full flex flex-row justify-end border-t pt-4 space-x-4">
          <button type="button" class="px-4 py-2 text-primary hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button type="submit" class="px-4 py-2 bg-primary text-white hover:bg-primary-hover rounded-xl">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the way you're fetching/storing the values in the objects, the exception states that it is unable to fetch the child object or the value of child object. You might want to debug or put a logger to check the values in the objects right before returning the flow on your computer, it can give you an idea.